# How to arrange a connection between Azure Data Factory and Azure Data Explorer when both are in private VNETs?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer, azure-virtual-network

I am completely new to Azure Data Explorer and Azure Data Factory. So, I would like to seek your suggestions in implementing below requirement.

- My data source is an API. My destination is Azure Data Explorer.
- I need to use Azure Data Factory for data transformations. So, I built a Pipeline in Azure Data Factory to process and transform the API response.
- Transformed API response should be ingested into Azure Data Explorer.

Now, my problem is both my Azure Data Explorer and Azure Data Factory is private access and lies behind a virtual network (of course, both are in same subnet).

As per the [Microsoft documentation on ADF connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview), ADF does not support connection to ADX using Managed Private Endpoint.

**My Approach:**

- Azure Data Factory has to process the API response and create csv
  files in Azure storage blob.
- Create Event Grid (Blob Storage) data connection in Azure Data
  Explorer. So that when csv files are created in storage account, data
  will be ingested to Azure Data Explorer tables.

Do we have any better approach to implement this scenario? (FYI. during each API invocation, I many need to process 30K to 40K records and need to do this for hundreds of customers. This pipeline will process millions of records in each run).

Answer (score 0):

here is what you could do.

1. create a managed integration runtime in ADF and make sure that it gets deployed in a line of sight to ADX and your source (same vnet as ADX and the source)
2. a) In case ADX is vnet injected (not recommended): connect to ADX using private- OR
   b) in case there is a private endpoint for ADX: connect to ADX using the regular url of the cluster